# How can I made a vertical line with a text in center?

Tags: html, css

I tried to make a clone of a form which has a vertical line `<span  class="vertical-line">or</span>` with a text in center!
So How can I make a line looks like

[this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y39C.png)
I think I might be using `hr` but it create a horizontal line instead of vertical bu might be if we do some css to rotate it, I don't know what is the best way of doing it.
That's what I have tried so far:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(147, 88, 134);
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
}

.tit2 {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tit1 {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.goo {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.face {
  background-color: rgb(27, 122, 255);
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.git {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.git,
.face,
.goo {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(186, 183, 183);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#login {
  background-color: rgb(147, 88, 134);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 7px;
}

.botona2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.tout {
  border: 2px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px 10px #dbdbdb;
}

.vertical-line {
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 130px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p class="tit1">Simo App</p>
  <p class="tit2">Login</p>
</header>
<div class="tout">
  <h1>Chose a Login Method</h1><br><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button class="goo"> Google</button><br>
      <button class="face">Facebook</button><br>
      <button class="git">Github</button><br>
    </div>
    <span class="vertical-line">or</span>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <form>
        <label><input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="botona2"></label><br>
        <label><input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="botona2"></label><br>
        <label><input type="submit" value="Login" id="login"></label>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make a line and position text over it using `position: absolute;`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.word {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="word">or</div>                                      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is a full size column (12) for the mobile version. So between the two col-sm-6 elements is this new one. Then you align everything to the center and create the circle normally. Next for SM screens or above it is necessary to do absolute positioning on the new block so that it doesn't count as the bootstrap column size. Then you insert it center-aligned with flexbox and make some changes, but in the end it's just centerings. The only thing that affects the sm-6 blocks are the new margins I inserted (pr-sm-25px and pl-sm-25px) so that the middle block doesn't invade the space of the rest of the content. There is very little screen encroachment, but this is due to the size of the already existing content, my rule is following the bootstrap grid.

Edit: This only works for two columns. As I put the absolute positioning if this grid has more columns or more items inserted (for example, 4 col-6 columns) then the positioning should be different. But I don't think this will change as it's not an incremental list.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    background-color: rgb(147, 88, 134);
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
}

.tit2 {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.tit1 {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.goo {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.face {
    background-color: rgb(27, 122, 255);
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.git {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.git,
.face,
.goo {
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

h1 {
    color: rgb(186, 183, 183);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#login {
    background-color: rgb(147, 88, 134);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 7px;
}

.botona2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.tout {
    border: 2px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px 10px #dbdbdb;
}

.middle-block {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: -1;
}

.middle-block-center {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
    color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 12px;
}

.middle-block-line {
    background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 90px);
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .middle-block {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .middle-block-center {
        padding: 14px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .middle-block-line {
        height: 100%;
        width: 2px;
    }

    .pr-sm-25px {
        padding-right: 25px !important;
    }

    .pl-sm-25px {
        padding-left: 25px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vertical line</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <p class="tit1">Simo App</p>
        <p class="tit2">Login</p>
    </header>
    <div class="tout">
        <h1>Chose a Login Method</h1><br><br>
        <div class="row position-relative">
            <div class="col-sm-6 pr-sm-25px">
                <button class="goo"> Google</button><br>
                <button class="face">Facebook</button><br>
                <button class="git">Github</button><br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 middle-block">
                <div class="middle-block-line"></div>
                <div class="middle-block-center">
                    <span>OR</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 pl-sm-25px">
                <form>
                    <label><input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="botona2"></label><br>
                    <label><input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="botona2"></label><br>
                    <label><input type="submit" value="Login" id="login"></label>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this code not respansive

Comment: @hamzanamsaoui And yes. It is between the smallest screen and the SM screen. Why? Because the asker's code uses SM in the block. If he used MD I would make the responsiveness between the screen MD or smaller which would be more common and more visible this difference. Maybe you didn't see it because you didn't shrink the screen enough as the SM screen is already small.

Comment: To make it responsive to the MD screen, just change the @media values to the MD grid